# Delphi use TTask in TWebModule (ISAPI - IIS)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, isapi

I have a ISAPI dll on IIS built with TWebModule.

I have an WebModule action that perform 5 separate tasks. I want use TTask from system.threading and perform this tasks in parallell before send the response to the client.

WebModule is already multithreaded, i think it run each request in separate thread.

Is safe to use TTask in WebModule action?

In this case, the request run in a thread and create other 5 threads... Also, TTask has a global thread pool, in my scenario tasks from different request going in the same pool...

Comment: Yes, it's safe to do threading in TWebModule, but you will have to wait for the threads (to finish `TTask.WaitforAll` before you can return a completed response to the caller. I'm not sure what will happen if you return a response before the tasks are completed to be honest. ISAPI may destroy the webmodule before the tasks are completed, or it may wait for the tasks to be completed. Someone else might have better experience with this than me.

Comment: TTask has internal thread pool with a max number of thread based on number of the cpu. This thread pool is shared for process. Each request that share the same ISAPI process, share the same thread pool, this can be a possible issue, because each request need to wait for a free thread into the pool.